# Visual Studio: How to view "Advanced" properties in the Properties window?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

i need to see the [ClientRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) of a form as i'm designing it. This particular property is tagged as "[Advanced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsablestate.aspx)", and by default is hidden from the Properties window:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), ...]
public Rectangle ClientRectangle
```

If the `ClientRectangle` property i want to look at is out, then i guess i can settle for the advanced `ClientSize` property:

```
[..., EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public Size ClientSize
```

The documentation for the [EditorBrowsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute leads to [an enumeration with 3 values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsablestate.aspx):

> **Always** The property or method is always browsable from within an
> editor.
>
> **Never** The property or method is never browsable from within an editor.
>
> **Advanced** The property or method is a feature that only advanced users
> should see. An editor can either show
> or hide such properties.

Apparently i am an "advanced user", so how do tell Visual Studio that i am an *advanced user* so i can see the *advanced properties*?

---

### Update One

The [linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) page talks about being able to enable Intellisense and the Properties Window to show advanced memebers:

> In Visual C#, you can control when
> advanced properties appear in
> IntelliSense and the Properties Window
> with the Hide Advanced Members setting
> under Tools | Options | Text Editor |
> C#. The corresponding
> [EditorBrowsableState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsablestate.aspx) is [Advanced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsablestate.advanced.aspx).

Unfortunatly this option seems to, in reality, only apply to Intellisense. Having it unchecked does not make advanced properties visible in the Properties Window

**Note:** the option is unchecked by default.

Answer (score 2):

Hans Passant's answer at [Finding and using hidden properties(such as DisplayRectangle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708771/finding-and-using-hidden-propertiessuch-as-displayrectangle/3708900#3708900) cleared this for me: it can't be done. The EditorBrowsable is only for the TEXT editor, and the attribute that controls the display in the Properties window is "Browsable(false)".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [link you provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx):

> In Visual C#, you can control when
>   advanced properties appear in
>   IntelliSense and the Properties Window
>   with the Hide Advanced Members setting
>   under Tools | Options | Text Editor |
>   C#. The corresponding
>   EditorBrowsableState is Advanced.

Comment: i have it unchecked and the items do not appear in the Properties Window.